# 'myname'@'%' can access to mysql server remotely but not with 'myname'@'123.456.489.%'

Tags: mysql, windows-10, windows-server-2019

I am working on accessing to mysql server remotely. My home pc to pc at the office.

I can access with 'myname'@'%'.

[image]

but I can't with 'myname'@'123.456.489.%'. '123.456.489.012'(redacted) is the IP address(IPv4) of my home pc.

[image]

I got this error:

[image]

I don't know why.

Comment: The error message looks like an IPv6?

Comment: (456 and 489 are not valid IPv4 octets; I hope that was just redacting.)

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL server is resolving IP addresses to names before checking whether the connection is allowed. Thus it is checking the hostname of your IP address instead of the address itself, which is what you had configured.

You can turn off this behavior with `skip-name-resolve`.

For example:

```
 [mysqld]
 skip-name-resolve
```